# Sharepoint: Can a Content Type have a site column of type file?

Tags: sharepoint

I know a content type has an attachments collection but is it possible to have a site column of type file? That is not part of attachments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - a content type either represents a file or it doesn't. You can't have a file as metadata to a content type that does not derive from document.

-Oisin

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can make your content type inherited from the Document content type.

Comment: those content types unfortunately don't support an attachments collection. - but thanks :)